# Resignation in lieu of being terminated sample letter

Tags: resignation, termination

Does anyone have a sample letter to share for resignation in lieu of termination?

Comment: Do you have a reason why "in lieu of being terminated" is important? Or to put it differently, why wouldn't a "normal" resignation letter work for you?

Comment: A letter saying "I quit as of such-and-such a date" isn't a complicated thing.

Answer (score 4):

Either you are already terminated, in which case a gesture of resigning is pointless, or you are concerned you are about to be, in which case you should just resign without referencing (and thereby acknowledging) the possible cause